# Regenerating a Corrupted Git Repo from Log Files?

Tags: git, corruption, fsck

I hit a random bluescreen on windows and when I restarted, my git repo was corrupted. It's a local-only repo and my backups are several weeks old. I've tried a number of different things (documented below) to get it working, but to no avail. Re-cloning the local repo yields the same corruption as the original. I can't commit anything new to the repo.

However, `git log` and `git show` still appear to work perfectly. Is there some way I can recreate a new git repo from the output of these commands?

---

What I have tried to get it working again:

git status does not work:

```
> git status --long -v
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: failed to read object 143fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465: 
> git fsck --full
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
error: unable to unpack 143fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465 header
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: loose object 143fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465 (stored in .git/objects/14/3fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465) is
corrupt
> mv .git/objects/14/3fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465 .git/objects/14/3fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465.bak
> git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (56357/56357), done.
broken link from    tree 85532cceff0ea16036538bfb47adc1f1ecdb1009
              to    tree 143fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465
...
missing tree 143fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465
...
```

I've also tried the following, which did not help:

```
> git checkout 444ea90502abc17eb2e55365e550a2e0dc95af61
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: failed to read object 143fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465: Invalid argument
> git reset --hard
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: failed to read object 143fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Try `git write-tree` on a copy to see if this fixes it!

Comment: Unfortunately not: `>git write-tree` output: `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` still get the same error: `> git status` output:
`fatal: unable to read tree 143fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465`

Comment: Try the `--missing-ok` switch, `git write-tree --missing-ok`, hopefully that should fix it.

Comment: Just tried it. I got the same exact output.

Comment: Damn! There's one more command, with a similar switch, `git mktree`, see if that helps.

Comment: Nope :( `git ls-tree master . | git mktree --missing` output: `error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
error: unable to unpack 143fd2fe59980f9b4aec9b1b696e4d2ab5bd0465 header
85532cceff0ea16036538bfb47adc1f1ecdb1009`